# While debugging different id for a object in eclipse means different instances?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging an android project in eclipse. And I am seeing two different id for a class variable. Does that means both are different instances?

Comment: what do you mean by two different id?

Comment: Probably the answer to your question is "yes", but you should really clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if they have different object Id's, they are different instances.